# UiTableview Sequeing with didselectrowAtindex returns previous selection?

Tags: ios5, uitableview, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

i hope someone can please help me with this. Im doing something really wrong here. Im trying to seque to a detailview. The problem is that the first time i select it, it returns a nil value, the second, third, etc time it returns the value i selected before.

I hope someone can please help me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Greetings,

jaco

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

      NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
      NSArray *HS = [sect objectForKey:[alles objectAtIndex:section]];
      passString = [HS objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   }


 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

     SiTDetailViewController *vcTarget = [segue destinationViewController];

    vcTarget.mijnString = passString;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hehe...figured it out. was kinda silly of me the ' delay'  was because i used both seque and didSelectRowAtIndexPath.
This is how it worked fine:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

  NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
  NSArray *HS = [sect objectForKey:[alles objectAtIndex:path.section]];
  passString = [HS objectAtIndex:path.row];
  SiTDetailViewController *vcTarget = [segue destinationViewController];
  vcTarget.mijnString = passString;

}
```